# Why use nodejs upload exception

Tags: exception, node.js

**code**

```
form.parse(request, function(error, fields, files) {
    console.log('parsing done');

    fs.renameSync(files.upload.path, 'c:/tmp/test.png');
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.write('received image:<br/>');
    response.write('<img src="/show" />');
    response.end();
});
```

**exception info**

return binding.rename(pathModule._makeLong(oldPath)),

Error:ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\esdafdace32323432a3f'

    
at Object.renameSync(fs.js:330:18)

Answer (score 4):

This because [`fs.rename()` can't move file between two different disks](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2703#issuecomment-3824789)
Other `renameSync` doesn't create new folder, so you should ensure  the `tmp/` is must exist.
You need creat  tmp folder in your sourcecode file folder,then set the `uploadDir`  like so:

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.uploadDir = "tmp";
  console.log("about to parse");
  form.parse(request, function(error, fields, files) {
    console.log(files.upload.path);
    try{
        fs.renameSync(files.upload.path, "tmp/test.jpg");
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write("received image:<br/>");
    response.write("<img src='/show' />");
    response.end();
  });
```

Comment: `rename doesn't create new folders` Thank you for that! Solved my problem!